# React JS creation problems

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Trying to create a new react JS project.

I keep getting this error.

Get the same error when using Visual Studio code, as well.

```
npm ERR! code EIO
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\James\Desktop\School\x\my-app\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-transform-for-of-b2ccfdcc
npm ERR! errno -4070
npm ERR! EIO: i/o error, mkdir 'C:\Users\James\Desktop\School\x\my-app\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-transform-for-of-b2ccfdcc'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-19T07_50_10_955Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\James\Desktop\School\x
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to create a react app?

Comment: i would strongly recommend you forget about the installation steps from your professor and use this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app.

Comment: and this https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html . both the links will be useful to you. use whichever you find easy.

Comment: @AmrAhmed yes i am. and Jay will check those out thanks for the replies

Answer (score 0):

According to this [github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6776) issue, you need to:

> uninstall node js and delete all its files in local and cache and all
> the node modules and npm and npm cache folder in this directory.

After it done, you just need to reinstall the npm, this should do the job.